# What is the relationship between the mean of a continuous variable and expected value?

Tags: mean, expected-value

What is the relationship between the mean of a continuous variable and expected value? How are they connected?

Comment: Please tell us what your understanding of these two terms is, because for many people they are synonyms.  What distinction do you make between them?

Comment: Expected value is the same as saying the mean, correct? The mean of continuous value would be the average (mean) of all possible values, right? So - they would be the same thing, no?

Answer (score 1):

As you and @whuber suggested in the comments, the expected value and the (arithmetic) mean of a random variable (continuous or otherwise) are the same thing.

"Mean" does have a few other meanings that "expected value" doesn't. For example, there is such a thing as the sample mean, but one would not speak of a sample expected value. Also, "mean" may be used to refer to measures of central tendency other than the arithmetic mean, such as the geometric mean.

"Expectation" is a synonym of "expected value".